# How to set the current task status to not started?

Tags: workflow-activity, custom-action

I've created a Custom Workflow Activity, and i'm using it at an Approval Workflow.
Now, I want to set the current task status to "Not Started" from the Custom Activity, but got nothing so far.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to have a field in the actual item's list that says not started?

Comment: The task status (Completed, Not Started, etc), I want to set it to Not Started from the Custom Activity when certain condition is accomplished or when an Exception occurs. Then the user has to interact with the workflow again to fix this.